# Ant: copy the same fileset to multiple places

Tags: ant

I need an Ant script that will copy one folder to several other places. As a good obedient programmer, I want not to repeat myself. Is there any way of taking a fileset like this:

```
<copy todir="${target}/path/to/target/1">
    <fileset dir="${src}">
        <exclude name='**/*svn' />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

And storing the `fileset` in a variable so it can be re-used?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Declare an id attribute on the fileset and then reference it in each copy task.

For example:

```
<project name="foo">
  <fileset id="myFileSet" dir="${src}">
    <exclude name='**/*svn' />
  </fileset>
  ...
  <target name="copy1">
    <copy todir="${target}/path/to/target/1">
      <fileset refid="myFileSet"/>
    </copy>
  </target>
  <target name="copy2">
    <copy todir="${target}/path/to/target/2">
      <fileset refid="myFileSet"/>
    </copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Correct. This is defined here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html in the section "Define a FilterSet and reference it later."

Comment: Note that some fileset selectors can have side effects which mean referring to the same fileset twice will not get the same results. For example: `<modified/>` will update its cache after the first run, and re-referring to the fileset later, assuming no changes in the underlying files, will return an empty set.

Comment: @DanGravell I'm facing this same problem with <modified />.  Do you know how to work around it?

Comment: Store the fileset in a variable?

Comment: @gyleg5 My workaround was to use foreach, and process files sequentially, instead of trying to use mutable fileset more than once.

Answer (score 29):

[Rich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164631/ant-copy-the-same-fileset-to-multiple-places/1164661#1164661) is probably better for your specific problem, but the generic way of reusing code in Ant is a [`<macrodef>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

```
<macrodef name="copythings">
  <attribute name="todir"/>
  <sequential>
    <copy todir="@{todir}">
      <fileset dir="${src}">
        <exclude name='**/*svn' />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>

<copythings todir="/path/to/target1"/>
<copythings todir="/path/to/target2"/>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The actual accepted answer is repeated code, which is exactly what the OP said he was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Upvoted first answer already, but you can also use a mapper to copy to multiple destinations.